# Groovy StreamingMarkupBuilder output XML separator

Tags: xml, groovy, streamingmarkupbuilder

I'm currently using in my groovy script the `StreamingMarkupBuilder` to produce my output XMl. Works all pretty well but when I have multiple elements with the same name in the source message, do I have an option to add separatos?

```
<Organisation>
   <Name>Name1</Name>
   <Name>Name2</Name>
   <Name>Name3</Name>
</Organisation>`
```

I use it in the following way:

```
builder.OrganisationName{
   NameFormatted Organisation.Name.toString() 
}
```

In my output I receive:

```
<NameFormatted>
   Name1Name2Name3
</NameFormatted>
```

I want to receveive the following - each element separated by blank or pre-defined separater

```
<NameFormatted>
  Name1 Name2 Name3
</NameFormatted>
```

Does anybody have a tip for me?

Thanks Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try in the following way:

```
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def slurped = new XmlSlurper().parseText('''<Organisation>
   <Name>Name1</Name>
   <Name>Name2</Name>
   <Name>Name3</Name>
</Organisation>''')

println slurped.Name

def builder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
def output = builder.bind {
    OrganisationName {
        NameFormatted slurped.Name.join(' ')
    }
}
println XmlUtil.serialize(output)
```

Other separators can also be passed to `join` instead of space.

Comment: Thanks a lot! join(' ') does the job.